# Unresolved times operator

Tags: operator-overloading, kotlin

I have the following [code](https://github.com/elect86/glm/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/main/quaternion.kt#L198-L202):

```
val temp1 = Quat(1f, Vec3(0, 1, 0)).normalize()
val temp2 = Quat(.5f, Vec3(1, 0, 0)).normalize()

val a = temp1 * Vec3(0, 1, 0)
val transformed0 = a * temp1.inverse() // error
```

The first `*` is correctly resolved in the `Quat` class with this [operator](https://github.com/elect86/glm/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/quat/Quat.kt#L129):

```
operator fun times(b: Vec3) = mul(Vec3(), this, b)
```

So `a` is a `Vec3` and on the last line we got a `Vec3 * Quat`

And this second operator I'd like to use is defined at top level in this [file](https://github.com/elect86/glm/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/quat/quat_operators.kt#L98):

```
operator fun Vec3.times(b: Quat) = mul(Vec3(), this, b)
```

I tried to enforce by typing:

`import times`

but among the suggested `times` there isn't the one I am looking for

What's the problem?

Comment: What is the return type of `temp1.inverse`? When you invoke `times` extension in a functional form, like `a.times(temp1.inverse())` is it resolved correctly?

Comment: ah, it was tricky... I wrote it in functional form and Intellij was jumping between resolved and unresolved.. alt+enter, import, it resolved it definitely. Switched back to operator, flawless.. Thanks Ilya, if you want to answer, I'll accept that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the extension `operator fun Vec3.times(b: Quat)` is defined in the package `quat`, you need to specify that package name when importing the operator:

```
import quat.times
// or
import quat.*
```